# Was this an unusual landing sequence for an airliner?

Tags: airliner, commercial-aviation

About a month ago I encountered an unusual landing during a flight from Bangkok to Krabi airport. We were flying Boeing 737.

We took off 30 minutes late. Our flight should've taken 90 minutes but it actually took less than 70 minutes so we arrived almost on time.

The seatbelt sign turned on around the 60th minute while we were still probably in 10000 meters (I don't know the cruising altitude for sure). The whole landing took less than 10 minutes. I guess the landing gear was deployed at around 6000 meters which seemed unusually high to me. The pilot also performed several rather sharp roll maneuvers and at one point he broke his descend and even entered a rather sharp climb. All this with landing gear out. I have to say that many passengers were quite terrified at the moment. The landing itself was hard but not that much.

I have been  wondering if it was a common maneuver (to decrease speed perhaps?) and would be interested to learn more about it. Does it have something to do with the flight speedup? How is it even possible to be so much faster on such a short flight?

Comment: Passenger descriptions of altitude, speed, bank angle, and configuration are notoriously unreliable from inside the cabin, even among experienced pilots.  I'm sure your flight was normal.

Comment: If you provide date and flight number maybe we can dig up more things for you. And relating flight schedule http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/why-do-airlines-over-estimate-over-calculate-flight-times

Comment: @abelenky may have answered your doubt. It is quite difficulf, from the cabin, to describe maneuvers, altitudes and other pilot's duties.

Comment: @eduardoguilherme I know that my observations are probably vastly inaccurate. Still, this flight was a lot different to what I am used to and judging by the reactions of copassengers I was not alone. I have no doubt that the pilot had it under control. I was just wondering if it could be due to time, specific location of the airport or some other reason. Maybe every flight to Krabi is like that I don't know :)

Comment: @Honza Brabec, is it possible to tell us the flight number, the date and the airlines, please? And also, the flight time (origin and destination airport)

Comment: @vasin1987 SL-8574 01 Feb 2016 11:05 AM Thai Lion, Bangkok, Krabi

Comment: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/sl8574/#8e80428 this route seems to always depart late and arrive on time.

Comment: `I guess the landing gear was deployed` - how do you know?

Comment: An airliner wanting to do a steep descent might well deploy flaps and similar devices, which could sound like the landing gear being deployed.

Comment: One reason passenger reports are unreliable is [spatial disorientation](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/760.ppt&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj1jJy1lqDLAhWD6yYKHaNpCCAQFggSMAE&sig2=OjJKKmQRq6Bk_HxlPpG50A&usg=AFQjCNHQA06X434LOuPSiRb7nFOg_9eHEA) Since you don't have instruments in front of you and only have a small window to look out of it's easy for the brain to be fooled into thinking the plane is doing something it really isn't. For instance you talk about a sharp climb. If you go the link posted by vasin1987 and pull up the speed/ altitude graph you will see that once

Comment: descent started the aircraft never climbed. Your senses were fooling you.

Comment: There's a free iPad app called Personal Black box that tracks where you are and displays aviation charts that you can uses for situational awareness.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you think the flight "should" take 90 minutes?
You really mean it was listed for 90 minutes on the schedule.
Airlines almost always pad their scheduled times so that their on-time arrivals stats are favorable, and to account for normally expected delays.

Scheduled time is also typically measured "gate-to-gate", while most passengers only observe the flight-time (takeoff-to-landing)

I see the distance is 350 miles, and would probably take a 737 about 60 minutes of actual flight time.  So I don't think your flight was speeding or otherwise behaving abnormally.